# Schema in placeholder programmatically

Tags: flyway

I am new to Flyway. Flyway is good and friendly.

I want to create and give schema name for my tables in V1__Initial_structure.sql file. I don't know where to assign value to the placeholder. I have configured Flyway programmatically. My sql file contains,

create schema  ${schemaName}

create table ${schemaName}.brand(brand_code IDENTITY,
                    brand_name varchar(50) unique not null, active char(1) default 'Y')

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method you are looking for: http://flywaydb.org/documentation/javadoc/com/googlecode/flyway/core/Flyway.html#setPlaceholders(java.util.Map)